# ImportError: cannot import name 'rnn_cell'

Tags: python, tensorflow

Using tensorflow 1.0.1 on windows and linux

While I run :

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import rnn, rnn_cell
```

I get:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'rnn_cell'

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try "from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops import rnn_cell"

Comment: Thanks, it's works

Answer (score 4):

Tensorflow 1.0 has change much. rnn_cell is not in the /tensorflow/python/ops path. When you search in the tensorflow doc, you can find rnn_cell in doc befor 1.0 is at tf.nn.rnn_cell such as doc [0.11](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/rnn_cell/) or doc [0.12](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/rnn_cell/rnn_cell_wrappers__rnncells_that_wrap_other_rnncells_).

In tensorflow 1.0 you can find `tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/rnn_cell.py` or `tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.impl.py`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops import rnn_cell
```